# How do I run an old version of Xcode on the latest macOS Server?

Tags: xcode, macos, server

When I try to connect Xcode 7.3.1 to macOS Server 5.2 (released Sept. 20, 2016) I get this error message:

"The version of Xcode you selected is older than the minimum version supported by Server."

[image]

I cannot use Xcode 8.x+ for the project because of swift-related issues that can't be easily refactored.

If there is no way to escape this issue then is there a way to download an older version of MacOS Server that supports Xcode 7.3.1?  I cannot find any way to download older versions of macOS Server.

Comment: "Swift-related issues that can't be easily refactored"? Xcode 7.3.1 has Swift 2.2, Xcode 8 has Swift 2.3, they are nearly the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'nearly the same' doesn't translate to 'compiles and runs in Xcode 8' for the hundreds of swift components I am using.

Comment: Swift 3 is the "new Swift version" for Xcode 8 which comes with big changes. Swift 2.3 is for those like you or me, who don't can't upgrade yet for compatibility reasons (or just don't want to for whatever reasons) so they can use their old Swift code with Xcode 8. I'm stuck to backwards compatibility myself because I'm using many old Swift 2.2 cocoapods (who by the way just run after you add "SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3" in their build settings). The changes are absolutely minor, please just run the migration assistant and see your code running on Xcode 8 in no time.

Comment: And no, you can't get a old version of Xcode server, I looked for you. You can even find it in apples archive. If you insist to use an old version of OS X Server 5.1, you find it with ease on various pirate sites. But I'd recommend you to just use your code as Swift 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find OS X Server 5.1 anymore if it's not even in Apples archive (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Your way to go here is to use Swift 2.3 as "Legacy Swift Language Version" instead of Swift 3 for your project.

> In addition to Swift 3, Xcode 8 supports development with Swift 2.3, a minor update to the Swift 2.2 language built to work with the new SDKs for macOS Sierra, iOS 10, tvOS 10, and watchOS 3. This is intended to allow developers to immediately move to these latest SDKs, even for projects that may be late in development with Swift 2.2 and not yet ready to move to Swift 3. Xcode 8 can migrate your code to the new Swift 2.3 changes, primarily related to nullability clarity that's been added to the new SDKs.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36

If you are using CocoaPods add this to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
            config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = 'YourTeamID/'
        end
    end
end
```

Please try using the Migration Assistent (Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax... and choose "Convert to Swift 2.3").

Comment: It looks like you have a problem very similar to mine.  Unfortunately, I cannot auto-convert our cocoa pods' code to swift 2.3.  The teams responsible for that code are working on getting the it converted but there are at least dozens of man-hours still needed to convert.  Thus, I cannot use Xcode 8 for this particular project at this point in time.

Comment: You add this to your Podfile and run your pod install. In most cases, the pods stay still Swift 2.2, but the extension above in your Podfile adds the tag `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3` to it and tells Xcode to use your team profile for provisioning and they should just run (in my case were nine Swift 2.2 pods, and they did just run). This can't even be called "convert". It's just telling Xcode, that it's still the old version. There may be some very minor adjustments after this, but they'll be issues, Xcode already offers to auto-fix them. Did you try it?

Comment: There is no way the migration to Swift 2.3 can take dozens of man-hours, to prevent this it's the sole purpose of the "legacy version" aka 2.3. You still will have to upgrade to version 3 in future, but for now, you don't have to. I do think that the team mistake the migration to Swift 2.3 with the migration to Swift 3.